# Value referenced by NEW on an unchanged column in an UPDATE trigger

Tags: sql, database, sqlite, triggers

I have a table `Group_Members` with a `DELETE` trigger and an `UPDATE` trigger. The `DELETE` trigger updates some rows in `A` hence invoking the `UPDATE` trigger.

Here's the `DELETE` trigger code:

```
UPDATE Group_Members
SET Role = 'Admin'
WHERE JoinDate = (SELECT MIN(JoinDate)
                  FROM Group_Members
                  WHERE GroupName = OLD.GroupName);
```

Here's the invoked `UPDATE` trigger code:

```
INSERT INTO Group_Notifications (Destination, Source, "Group", Type)
VALUES (OLD.Username, NEW.Affector, OLD.GroupName, 'Membership Promotion');
```

My question is: what would be the value referenced by `NEW` in the `UPDATE` trigger given the column value has not been changed i.e. in this scenario, what would be the value referenced by `NEW.Affector`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`new` has the column values as they will be after the `UPDATE`. So if `affector` isn't changed by the `UPDATE`, its value after the `UPDATE` will be the same value it had before. In that case `new.affector` has the same value as `old.affector`.